# On a conjecture that two intersections are at $\big(\pm\frac{S}m, S\big)$ (about linear equations)

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, proof-writing, proof-explanation, conjectures

Suppose we have two linear equations, $y=mx$ and $y=-mx$ , inserted on the same plane for $m>0$. These equations are going to have an intersection at $(0,0)$. Now, let $$\begin{align}S&=1+\sum_{i=2}^{m-1}\left(i-\frac12\right)\\ &\stackrel{\small\text{or}}{=}1+\left\{\bigg(2-\frac12\bigg)+\bigg(3-\frac12\bigg)+\cdots+\bigg(m-1-\frac12\bigg)\right\}.\end{align}$$

If we insert the equation, $y={m^2+1 \over 2}$, on the selfsame plane, then this horizontal line will pass through both the aforementioned linear equations, thus forming two more intersections.

> > **Conjecture:**
>
> The two intersections are at $\big(\pm\frac{S}m, S \big)$, such that the positive $x$ coordinate is on the RHS of the $y$ axis, and the negative $x$ coordinate is on the LHS of the $y$ axis.

This is my own conjecture actually... and I can't seem to prove it. The following is my attempt, in which I did make some progress... but it is not a *proof* (...yet).

---

*Attempt*: $$\begin{align}S&=1+\left\{\bigg(2-\frac12\bigg)+\bigg(3-\frac12\bigg)+\cdots+\bigg(m-1-\frac12\bigg)\right\}\tag{given} \\ \\ 2\cdot S&=2+(4-1)+(6-1)+\cdots+(2m-2-1)\tag{$\times 2$} \\ &=\require{cancel}{\cancel2}+(4-1)+(6-1)+\cdots+(2m\cancel{-2}-1)\tag{$2-2=0$} \\ &= (4-1)+(6-1)+\cdots+(2m-1)\tag{simplifying} \\ &=\sum_{i=2}^m(2i-1).\tag{$\ast$}\end{align}$$

Here, we can use the following lemma to enable us to write *Eq.* $(\ast)$ in closed form: $$\sum_{j=1}^n(2j-1)=n^2.$$ <sub><sup>The proof of this lemma can be found in [***Intermediate Mathematics: Proof by Induction***](https://www.plymouth.ac.uk/uploads/production/document/path/3/3745/PlymouthUniversity_MathsandStats_proof_by_induction.pdf) in Page $8$, Section $2$, Example $3$.</sup></sub>

By letting $n=m$ and $j=i$, we can rewrite this lemma and obtain the following: $$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^m(2i-1)&=(2\times 1-1)+\sum_{i=2}^m(2i-1) \\ \Leftrightarrow m^2&= 1+\sum_{i=2}^m(2i-1) \\ \Leftrightarrow \sum_{i=2}^m(2i-1)&= m^2-1 \\ \Leftrightarrow 2S&=m^2-1\end{align}$$ $$\boxed{\therefore S=\frac{m^2-1}{2}}\tag*{$\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \ \ \ \; \ \,$}$$

After rewriting and simplifying the $x$ coordinate in the ordered pair of the conjecture, it follows that it is equivalent to $$\bigg(\pm\frac{m^2-1}{2m}, \frac{m^2-1}{2}\bigg).$$ And now... where do I go? Factorising, where $m^2-1=(m+1)(m-1)$, does not appear to help. Additionally, I split the $x$ coordinate to write $$\bigg(\pm\bigg(\frac{m^2-4}{2m}+\frac{3}{2m}\bigg),\frac{m^2-1}{2}\bigg)$$ knowing that $$\frac{m^2-4}{2m}=\frac{m^2-2^2}{2m}=\frac{m}2+\frac{2}{m}=\frac{m}2-\bigg(-\frac{2}m\bigg).\tag{$\ast\ast$}$$ Now if we let $g_1$ and $g_2$ be gradients such that $g_1\perp g_2$ and $g_1=m\div 2$ then *Eq.* $(\ast\ast)$ will be equivalent to $g_1-g_2$. But this did not help either, albeit exploring in the realm of gradients.

---

May anyone like to share some input? Did I take the right approach, or is this tedious and not very efficient? If you'd like, you can either tell me where to go from here, or draft up a new proof (though I hope the latter does not take up too much of your time). And, since we are dealing with graphs, you can perhaps use the [***Desmos Graphing Calculator***](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) (or, if you like to live on the dangerous side, you can try answering this with what I used — a pen, ruler and graphing paper!). I will accept any kind of answer, even if it may be a mere hint, as long as the hint serves useful.

With that being said, my general skill level is strongest probably up to Year $12$ mathematics... I believe... I mean, I am in Year $10$ and most of my maths that I know — of which is completely foreign to the Year $10$ maths curriculum at school — is self-taught (thanks, MSE!). After taking some Year $11$ Maths Methods classes, specifically on algebra, I found it very easy, so in order to keep answers understandable (and to not waste your time), I will safely say my skill level does not reach university standards, although it might...?

Thank you in advance!

$\boxed{\stackrel{\centerdot\,\centerdot}{\smile}}$

Answer (score 3):

The conjecture actually never holds (no wonder why you can't prove it!). For example, when $m=5$, $S=17/2$. Now the equation $y=5x$ meets the line $y=(5^2+1)/2=13$ at $(x,y)=(13/5,13)$, whose $y$-coordinate is not the same as $S$.

---

Using the identity that $\sum_{i=1}^n i=n(n+1)/2$, \begin{align}S&=1+\sum_{i=2}^{m-1}\left(i-\frac12\right)=1-\left(1-\frac12\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}\left(i-\frac12\right)\\&=\frac12+\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}i-\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}\frac12=\frac12+\frac{(m-1)m}2-\frac{m-1}2\\\implies S&=\frac12(1+m^2-m-(m-1))=\frac{m^2-2m+2}2.\end{align} The intersection point between $y=\pm mx$ and $y=\frac{m^2+1}2$ occurs at $x=\pm\frac{m^2+1}{2m}$. However, $$\left(\pm\frac Sm,S\right)=\left(\pm\frac{m^2-2m+2}{2m},\frac{m^2-2m+2}2\right)$$ which is different to $$\left(\pm\frac{m^2+1}{2m},\frac{m^2+1}2\right)$$ As an addendum, for them to be the same, one can equate coordinates to get $$\frac{m^2-2m+2}{2m}=\frac{m^2+1}{2m}\implies m^2-2m+2=m^2+1\implies 2m=1\implies m=\frac12$$ which is not possible as $m\in\Bbb Z^+$.